# Pyspark Increment the timestamp column based on row_number value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am pulling the data from eventhub and I am getting 10 records in each packet and a timestamp is coming on each packet.
I want to explode the packet consisting of 10 records and I want to add the packet timestamp to each record incrementing by 1 sec when partitioned by EnqueuedTimeUtc and vehicleid

Below is the intermediate data that I have in the dataframe.

```
df.show()

+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+
|    EnqueuedTimeUtc|      vehicleid|   datetime_pkt    |
+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|
+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

expected output

```
+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    EnqueuedTimeUtc|      vehicleid|   datetime_pkt    | nw_datetime_pkt   |
+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|2022-05-01 07:19:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|2022-05-01 07:20:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|2022-05-01 07:21:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|2022-05-01 07:22:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|2022-05-01 07:23:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|2022-05-01 07:24:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|2022-05-01 07:25:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|2022-05-01 07:26:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|2022-05-01 07:27:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:46 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:43|2022-05-01 07:28:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|2022-05-01 07:19:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|2022-05-01 07:20:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|2022-05-01 07:21:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|2022-05-01 07:22:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|2022-05-01 07:23:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|2022-05-01 07:24:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|2022-05-01 07:25:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|2022-05-01 07:26:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|2022-05-01 07:27:43|
|5/1/2022 7:19:49 AM|86135903910    |2022-05-01 07:19:48|2022-05-01 07:28:43|
+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the above task by making use of Windowing functions.

steps:

1. add the row_number for partitionBy columns and add substract by 1 so that row_number starts by 0 instead of 1.
2. make use of lag function and create a new column nw_datetime_pkt.
3. make use of unix_timestamp function which take timestamp column and number of seconds to increment

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("vehicleid", "datetime_pkt").orderBy("datetime_pkt")) - 1) \
        .withColumn("nw_datetime_pkt", F.lag(F.col("datetime_pkt")).over(Window.partitionBy("vehicleid", "datetime_pkt").orderBy("datetime_pkt")))

df1 = df1.withColumn("nw_datetime_pkt", F.when(F.col("nw_datetime_pkt").isNull(), F.col("datetime_pkt")).otherwise((F.unix_timestamp("nw_datetime_pkt") + df1.rn).cast('timestamp')))
```